# Implement font menu item in notepad using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

while i am trying to implement font menu item in notepad , 
im not getting text changed , is there any mistake in my code

this is my code

```
private void fontMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontDialog objFontForm = new FontDialog();
    objFontForm.ShowDialog();

}
```

Comment: I may be mis-reading this but you're only showing the dialog and not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really simple example taken from [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fontdialog)

```
//Create FontDialog instance
FontDialog fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();
// Show the dialog.
DialogResult result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
// See if OK was pressed.
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Get Font.
    Font font = fontDialog1.Font;
    // Set TextBox properties.
    this.textBox1.Text = string.Format("Font is: {0}", font.Name);
    this.textBox1.Font = font;
}
```